# Multiple automatic discounts for memberships

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

So we have three membership levels - a 1 year, 2 year, and 3 year. The discount level for 1 year and 2 year are the same, but it is higher for the 3 year. I have the discounts for them set up the same way, except one applies to 1 and 2 year and the other applies to 3 year. However, only one is showing on our membership page. Is it a problem of there only being one allowed?

The point of the discount is that it automatically applies if the person still has a current membership. If it has expired, they are charged the full price.

The user that I am logged in as when looking at this membership page has the 3 year membership type.

Here's what I get on the membership renewal page, the setup for the 1 & 2 year discount, and the setup for the 3 year discount:

[image: Here's what I get on the membership renewal page:]

[image: Here's the setup for the 1 & 2 year memberships:]

[image: Here's the setup for the 3 year membership:]

Comment: I'm assuming the 3-year discount is set up the same way as the 1- and 2-year ones?  Any chance you could provide the screenshot of the discount config for the 3-year?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell it is. I've posted screenshots.

Comment: And what membership type does the user you're showing on the initial screenshot have?

Comment: Full Member - 3 Years

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue using the discount code configuration you provide in your screenshots and it appears that it has been reported to the developers of CiviDiscount [here](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/issues/202). So, bottom line is, your codes are set up correctly, but currently only one autodiscount can be applied per contribution or event page.

You may wish to offer funding in the same thread listed above if resolution of this issue is of high priority to you.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: The link doesn't appear to work?

Comment: @JenniSimonis I fixed the link!

Answer (score 1):

I've raised a PR on cividiscount extension https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/210 which fixes the similar use case. More details about the steps to replicate, etc in the PR description.

@jenni-simonis - Can you pls verify if it works for your case as well?

Thanks.

Comment: I made the change, cleared the Drupal cache and the Civi cache, but nothing changed on my renewal page. Am I missing clearing something somewhere?

Comment: Well, I would be happy to verify this, but have never heard back. I've posted both here and at the link you gave.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion, this fixed the issue where two autodiscounts can now be applied to the same event type (where the discount is driven by the price field); this does NOT fix a situation where multiple discounts need to be applied to the same price set (on the same event registration page) - e.g. I have an event where someone can buy a 1-day $20 ticket or 2-day $40 ticket, and I want two autodiscounts for members: $10 off for the 1-day option and $20 off for the 2-day option; this used to work (last time we used this successfully was in June 2018)

Comment: #215 (https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/215) solves it but I didn't regression test